# Reporting errors from a JavaFX application or any Java application

Tags: java, javafx, exception

I know this question is a bit outside the realm of Stack Overflow, but I'm not finding anything and I'm wondering if I'm searching for the wrong thing.

I developed a JavaFX application and I'm trying to keep track of when it crashes or gets an unexpected exception. I know there are countless of services and libraries to do this for web apps and I'm even aware of one or two for .Net applications, but I'm failing to find a promising solution for JavaFX.

I did find:

- [CrashFX](https://github.com/vinumeris/crashfx): it seems it's [not getting much development](https://github.com/vinumeris/crashfx/pulse/monthly) and it requires [me hosting the server](https://github.com/vinumeris/crashfx#how-to-run-the-web-app), which I'd rather not do if I can avoid.
- Crashlytics: it's only for Android, not for JavaFX

There are plenty of error trackers out there in the world, such as Sentry, Rollbar, etc. but all of them seem to designed for server applications which is different than client applications.

For example, in server applications it's very easy to wrap each request in a catch-all handler that will report the exception. A client application generates threads, each thread needs its own handler. The whole application may crash (actually, if something goes wrong, completely crashing is the correct thing to do instead of leaving an app misbehaving in the wrong state). At that point a popup should appear asking for some feedback and sending the report to the server.

An example of doing this by hand in .Net: https://stevenbenner.com/2010/01/reporting-of-unhandled-exceptions-in-your-distributable-net-application/

Comment: When you saying crashes you are referring to a system failure or to your app failure due to some unhandled exceptions? If your code is well safe which means you are handling every exception ( runtime ) then all you need is a log mechanism to inform/save a log with the actual error and time. In case i havent understand you correctly, let me know.

Comment: @JKostikiadis: crashes and or exceptions, after all, crashes in Java are just unhandled exceptions (I'm not too worried about the JVM itself crashing). Whether I catch all exceptions and log them or let the bubble up and have some sort of wrapper log them, works either way (and actually I might end doing a mix of those two scenarios).

Comment: You don't have to limit yourself to JavaFX; all you need is a Java-compatible SDK. Have you had a look at [Sentry](https://sentry.io/for/java/)?

Comment: @beatngu13: no, I don't have to limit myself to JavaFX; but JavaFX implies a desktop application and Sentry is designed for servers. Properly doing exception tracking for a client application means wrapping every thread or even the app itself and then saving the exception to disk and the next time the application runs (because it crashed), reporting the error. What I'm looking for would be the equivalent of Raygun WPF or Winforms.

Comment: Sentry is not only for servers, they even offer a SDK for Android apps. Have a look at their [integrations](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/modules/).

Comment: Sentry now has integration with logback, which means, you can easily log all catched exceptions to Sentry.